# Create a list of columns and sum them in a new column with Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I do know some posts are quite similar to my question but none of them succeded in giving me the correct answer. I want, for each row of a pandas dataframe, to perform the sum of values taken from several columns. As the number of columns tends to vary, I want this sum to be performed from a list of columns.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
df['Sum'] = df['Col A'] + df['Col E'] + df['Col Z']
```

I want it to be something like :

```
df['Sum'] = sum(list_of_my_columns)
```

or

```
df[list_of_my_columns].sum(axis=1)
```

But both of them return an error. Might be because my list isn't properly created? This is how I did it:

```
list_of_my_columns = [df['Col A'], df['Col E'], df['Col Z']]
```

But this doesn't seem to work... Any ideas ? Thank you !

Comment: df[list_of_my_columns].sum(axis=1)

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried this and it returns an index error :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need the list of columns. You need a list of column names:

```
list_of_my_columns = ['Col A', 'Col E', 'Col Z']
df['Sum'] = df[list_of_my_columns].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! You rightly pointed out my mistake! Using the column names is much more efficient than creating a new df. :)

Comment: Fyi, that produces the SettingWithCopyWarning Pandas warning:

`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. 
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead.` 

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 2):

Let me write as an answer

```
list_of_my_columns = [df['Col A'], df['Col E'], df['Col Z']]
```

Using `concat`

```
df['Sum']=pd.concat(list_of_my_columns,axis=1 ).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Works like a charm thank you! So you used the pd.concat function to create a temporary dataframe containing only my columns, right? Two questions :

- When I create a list of columns, are they duplicated in the variable meaning they take more space in the RAM?

- Same thing with the df generated with pd.concat, does the new dataframe takes up memory space as well? Or is it destroyed right after the sum has been computed?

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a `Series` (which is a column in pandas) and take the sum of each row and append it to the `Series`. Then just add the Series to the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', header=None)
col = pd.Series()

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    col.set_value(i, (row[0] + row[1] + row[2]))

df = df.assign(sum=col)

print(df)
```

Comment: When you use a loop by rows in pandas, you are almost surely doing it wrong.